# Cookies lost after hitting diff endpoints

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm setting my headers via 'Set-Cookie' and token name and value after I log in:

```
import express from "express";
import User from "../models/User.js";
import { hash } from "bcrypt";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

const router = express.Router();

const generateToken = (id) => {
  return jwt.sign({id}, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {expiresIn: '30d'})
}

router.post('/login', async (req,res) => {
  const {email, password} = req.body;

  const user = await User.findOne({email});

  console.log(user);

  if (user && (bcrypt.compare(password, user.hashedPassword))) {
    const token = generateToken(user.id);
    // res.cookie('token', token, {httpOnly: true, maxAge: 400000})
    // res.status(200)
    res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', `token=${token}`)
    .json({
      _id: user.id,
      firstName: user.firstName,
      lastName: user.lastName,
      email: user.email,
      token: token
    })
  } else {
    res.status(400)
    throw new Error('invalid credentials!')
  }
})
```

Then in my middleware:

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import User from '../models/User.js';

export const authMiddleware = async (req,res, next) => {
    const cookieToken = req.headers.cookie.split('=')[1];

    if (cookieToken) {
        try {
            
            const decoded = jwt.verify(cookieToken, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
    
                const user = await User.findById(decoded.id);
    
                req.userId = user.id;
    
                console.log(req.userId);
    
                next()
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            res.status(401);
            throw new Error('not authorized!')
        }
    }
}
```

And finally an endpoint other than my login:

```
import express from "express";
import Expense from "./../models/Expense.js";
import Category from "../models/Category.js";
import SubCategory from "../models/SubCategory.js";
import User from "../models/User.js";
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';


const router = express.Router();

router.get("/expenses", async (req, res) => {
  const userId = await req.userId;
  try {
    const expenses = await Expense.find({
      userId: userId
    })
      .populate("subCategory")
      .populate("category")
      .exec();
    console.log('user expenses: ', expenses);
    res.status(200).json(expenses);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });
  }
});
```

On Postman this does everything I need it to, but in the browser every cookie I look for is undefined. My thinking is that after login, the page is refreshed and the cookies are lost, but then I'm curious how to make them persistent. I'm using rtk query to make these calls, here's how I hit the expense endpoint:

```
export const api = createApi({
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({baseUrl: import.meta.env.VITE_BASE_URL}),
    reducerPath: "main",
    tagTypes: ["Kpis", "Categories", "Expenses", "Users", "Sub-Categories"],
    endpoints: (build) => ({
        getKpis: build.query<void, void>({
            query: () => "kpi/kpis/",
            providesTags: ["Kpis"]
        }),
        getCategories: build.query<Category[], void>({
            query: () => "category/categories/",
            providesTags: ["Categories"]
        }),
        getSubCategories: build.query<SubCategory[], void>({
            query: () => "subCategory/subCategories/",
            providesTags: ["Sub-Categories"]
        }),
        getExpenses: build.query<Expense[], void>({
            query: () => "expense/expenses/",
            providesTags: ["Expenses"]
        }),
        registerUser: build.mutation<User, User>({
            query: ({...user}) => ({
                url: 'user/register/',
                method: "POST",
                body: user
            })
        }),
        addExpense: build.mutation<{_id: string}, {category: string, subCategory:string, price:number, date: string | undefined}>({
            query: ({...expense}) => ({
                url: 'expense/expenses/',
                method: 'POST',
                body: expense
            })
        }),
        loginUser: build.mutation<User & {_id:string, token:string}, {email:string, password:string}>({
            query: ({...user}) => ({
                url: 'user/login/',
                method: "POST",
                body: user
            })
        }),
        createSubCategory: build.mutation<string, {name:string}>({
            query: ({...name}) => ({
                url: `subCategory/create/`,
                method: "POST",
                body: name
            })
        })
    })
})

export const {useGetKpisQuery, useGetCategoriesQuery, useGetExpensesQuery, useRegisterUserMutation, useAddExpenseMutation, useLoginUserMutation, useGetSubCategoriesQuery, useCreateSubCategoryMutation} = api;
```

Maybe my middleware is causing an issue? If so, here's index.js:

```
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import cors from "cors";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import helmet from "helmet";
import morgan from "morgan";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import kpiRoutes from "./routes/kpi.js";
import categoryRoutes from "./routes/category.js";
import subCategoryRoutes from "./routes/subCategory.js";
import expenseRoutes from "./routes/expense.js";
import userRoutes from "./routes/user.js";
import { authMiddleware } from "./middleware/authMiddleware.js";

dotenv.config();
const app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(helmet());
app.use(helmet.crossOriginResourcePolicy({ policy: "cross-origin" }));
app.use(morgan("common"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cors());

app.use("/kpi", authMiddleware, kpiRoutes);
app.use("/category", categoryRoutes);
app.use("/subCategory", authMiddleware, subCategoryRoutes);
app.use("/expense", authMiddleware, expenseRoutes);
app.use("/user", userRoutes);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 9000;

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(async () => {
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(`Server running on port: ${PORT}`);
    });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(`${error} connecting to DB`);
  });
```